Position colobar beneath two choropleth subplots
Following up on my previous question, I'm having some trouble repositioning my legend to where I want it to be. In the aforementioned post, my legend was attached to the second subplot, but I want to put it below the two plots. Such as in the left plot here.
Here's my existing code:
a_combined_path = 'c:\\mypath'
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1,2, layout='constrained')
fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
a_2020.plot(ax=ax1, column='Party Vote Share', cmap='Greens', edgecolor='black', linewidth = 0.5, norm=norm)
a_dublin.plot(ax=ax2, column='Party Vote Share', cmap='Greens', edgecolor='black', linewidth = 0.5, norm=norm)
ax1.set_axis_off()
ax2.set_axis_off()
ax1.set_title('Republic of Ireland', size = 16)
ax2.set_title('Dublin', size = 16)
fig.suptitle('Aontú vote share in the 2020 elections\nby constituency (Pct of total vote)', size = 16)
plt.savefig(a_combined_path, dpi=600)

I've tried putting legend=True, legend_kwds={loc: 'lower right'} in a_2020.plot(...), but apparently colorbar doesn't take loc as an argument. I've tried using fig.colorbar, but  I can't seem to get imshow to work with my dataframe. Also, it doesn't even need to strictly be a colorbar, I'd be perfectly happy with something like the legend here. I'm just trying to get it to be positioned in the lower center of my figure, something I mistakenly thought would be a straightforward exercise.
Any help would be much appreciated, as I've spent my day so far going in circles on this.

Without any data it is hard to test this out but if you are planning on using only one legend for both subplots you can use the following but you may need to fiddle around with the numbers inside the tuple for bbox_to_anchor. The four numbers inside the bbox_to_anchor tuple represent the coordinates of the anchor point for the legend box. However, only two of these numbers are typically used for positioning the legend. The first two numbers represent the horizontal and vertical positions of the anchor point relative to the subplot's axes. E.g. bboch_to_anchor = (0.5,0.5). If you want to specify the exact position of the legend box within the subplot, you can add additional arguments like width and height. E.g. bboch_to_anchor = (0.5,0.5,0.3,0.7). These numbers can be greater than 1 so try out different values.
# Add legends to subplots
ax1.legend(loc='upper left')  # For the first subplot
ax2.legend(loc='upper right') # For the second subplot

# Positioning the legend relative to the entire figure
fig.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0), bbox_transform=fig.transFigure)

If you would like to have seperate legends for each of the subplots, then you can try the following:
# Add legends to subplots
ax1.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
ax2.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5))

Again with these you can either use 2 or 4 numbers inside the tuple.
Hope this at least helps you on your path to finding a solution.

Thanks for the quick response, but I can't really test how bbox_to_anchor works with my data, as this approach only returns: No artists with labels found to put in legend.  Note that artists whose label start with an underscore are ignored when legend() is called with no argument. This makes me think that there is an argument missing in legend. Also fwiw, the data in 'Party Vote Share' is just a list of integers.
